# CreateRemoteThread failing with CreateProcessAsUser and CREATE_SUSPENDED

Tags: c++, windows, security, winapi, code-injection

I have a service (running as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM, in session 0). It creates two children using [CreateProcessAsUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) into the current user session (both running as domain\user, in session 1).

Child 1 we'll call **injector**, and child 2 we'll call **injectee**.

**Injectee** is created suspended with the `CREATE_SUSPENDED` process creation flag. **Injector** calls [CreateRemoteThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) against **injectee**. `CreateRemoteThread` fails with 8 (`ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY`), which after some googling looks like it's actually related to permissions.

What's interesting is the **injector** can successfully call `CreateRemoteThread` against the **injectee** process if **injectee** is just ran from the user account (`CreateProcess` with `CREATE_SUSPENDED` from user account).

If **injector** is ran from the user account, it can't `CreateRemoteThread` against the **injectee** child, but can against an **injectee** that was ran from the user account.

### Hopefully this diagram will make it easier to visualise :)

```
// With CREATE_SUSPENDED
// Session 0     -----------
//               | Service |
//               -----------
//                  // \\                          
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
// Session 1      //     \\                              
//               //       \\                             
//     ------------   N   ------------   N   ------------
//     | Injector | ----> | Injectee | <---- | Injector |
//     ------------       ------------       ------------
//                 \                        /            
//                  \ Y   ------------   Y /             
//                   ---> | Injectee | <---              
//                        ------------
```

Interestingly, if the `CREATE_SUSPENDED` flag is removed, all of the `CreateRemoteThread` scenarios succeed, but I need to use `CREATE_SUSPENDED`.

```
// Without CREATE_SUSPENDED
// Session 0     -----------
//               | Service |
//               -----------
//                  // \\                          
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
// Session 1      //     \\                              
//               //       \\                             
//     ------------   Y   ------------   Y   ------------
//     | Injector | ----> | Injectee | <---- | Injector |
//     ------------       ------------       ------------
//                 \                        /            
//                  \ Y   ------------   Y /             
//                   ---> | Injectee | <---              
//                        ------------
```

There must be some nuance in using `CreateProcessAsUser` from SYSTEM / session 0, which means that the child inherits something that denies `CreateRemoteThread` access, but I don't know what.

I'm using `CreateProcessAsUser` with all default parameters. MSDN says "The default security descriptor is that of the user referenced in the hToken parameter", and the token is obtained by [WTSQueryUserToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383840%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and is that of the current user.

Using Process Explorer to view the Security attributes of both types of **injectee** shows exactly the same information.

This is driving me crazy, what could it be?

Comment: Could be the process integrity level, I guess.  It might also be worth experimenting with the local Administrator account to see whether UAC is involved.  (But to be honest I'm surprised that you can ever successfully inject a thread into a suspended - and hence not yet fully initialized - process.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston - it is [documented behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682437.aspx): "*The `ExitProcess`, `ExitThread`, `CreateThread`, `CreateRemoteThread` functions, and a process that is starting (as the result of a `CreateProcess` call) are serialized between each other within a process. Only one of these events occurs in an address space at a time. This means the following restrictions hold: • During process startup ..., **new threads can be created**, but they do not begin execution until DLL initialization is done for the process.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau is correct in that a thread can be created, and it forces the process to be initialised before the thread runs. After some investigation, it seems as though Windows deems the child process to still be in session 0 until it's initialised (even though things like Process Explorer reports session 1). I'm torn between first creating a thread from the SYSTEM process to a `RET`/`RET 4` to initialise the child from session 0 to session 1, and then continuing as planned, or falling back on `RtlCreateUserThread` if `CreateRemoteThread` fails. Heck, maybe even both...